# Read a file using a program like Notepad while the file is being written to by another program?

Tags: c++, windows, file, service, io

> Read a file using a program like Notepad while the file is being written to by another program?

I've created a Windows Service application that logs continuously.

I want to inspect the current events of the service without closing it. To do this I open the `log.txt` in `Notepad`, but gets the message

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process

How can I read the log file without closing the service? After the service is closed, I can readily inspect every log entry in the file.

The file is being written by calls to `fopen_s` and `fprintf`, if that should be of any interest. Also, the service is programmed in `C/C++` on `Windows 10 64-bit`, running under `SCM` with default priviledges i.e. `LocalSystem`.

Comment: I always use notepad++ (a free download from somewhere, google search).  It can open log files while those are still being written (and it is better than notepad in a few other ways.

Comment: In this case, it could't open the file and read its contents :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx and then Remarks:

Files that are opened by fopen_s and _wfopen_s are not sharable. If you require that a file be sharable, use _fsopen, _wfsopen with the appropriate sharing mode constant—for example, _SH_DENYNO for read/write sharing.

Would that be a solution?

Comment: I guess so, I will try it. I don't understand why my question is downvoted.